# Can I password protect Work Sheets in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can I password protect an Excel 2010 worksheet.
I have an Excel file that contain 10 sheets according to locations. This file contains some MIS reports. The file is mailed to all locations daily and each location can view the sheet of the other location.
Is there a way I can password protect the sheets so that one location can only open the sheet related to its location.

Answer (score 1):

You can protect certain sheets from viewing: First hide all sheets which you want to be non-viewable. You can do this via context menu of the sheet tabs (at the bottom). Then password protect the complete workbook:`Tools -> Protection -> Protect Workbook`. This prevents unhiding the hidden sheets.

Note that it is probably not such a good idea to send confidential content to recipients who are not allowed to read said content, even if it is protected by a password. Apparently (I have not tried this myself), there exist password breakers for Excel.

Comment: It's actually extremely easy to strip the password from an excel workbook and you don't need a password breaker to do it. If you have PII that's on a need to know basis, you should be sending only the sheets that pertain to that location. While it is easier to send the entire workbook, it's very insecure and you have more risk of leaking said data.

Answer (score 0):

Try right-clicking on the sheet tab (at the bottom) and choose "Protect Sheet..."

Comment: It really is as simple as that. Keep in mind, though, that this feature is available in excel 2007 or later

Comment: @smc I think he wants to *hide* the sheets (make them non-viewable). The Excel sheet protection option only allows for locking content.

Comment: @ben, after reading through it once again, I agree. But snowdudes answer is still perfectly valid